# Common CRUD design issue - getting a newly added entity's ID

Tags: database

Is there any built-in database function (any db) that does something like this? Ie. ask the db to create a record and then return the ID that was automatically assigned to it.

Comment: Yes, they all do this. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: mubar: what database system are you working on? MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL, Access, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO table_name
(id, value)
VALUES
id_value, value
RETURNING id
INTO item_id;
```

Comment: if the database is generating the id, why are you including it in the insert statement?

Comment: You don't have to, of course, I put it there to make it clear what's being inserted and what's being returned.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
(id, value) /** assuming ID is a PRIMARY KEY with AUTOINCREMENT **/
VALUES
(null, value);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) function will send the last generated autoincrement number, per connection.